# A word for each form of a scenario that has more than one form?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have these two scenarios 1 and 2 in both of which a subject is put to an experiment but in two different environments. Each of these scenarios has two different forms, in one the subject has information x and in the other has not. How may I call each of these forms. For example, what word is a good choice for the blank in the following sentence?

> In the first ... of the first scenario, the subject has information x.

The words I have in mind but am not sure about are "variation" and "variant".

Comment: You could use version or form, also.

Comment: You might call them ***variants*** since they are *variations* on a theme.

Answer (score 2):

**Case**, according to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/case):

> " a particular situation or example of something"

Another word that could be used is **instance**, according to [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/instance):

> "A particular case."

In your example:

> In the first **case** of the first scenario, the subject has information x.
>
> In the first **instance** of the first scenario, the subject has information x.

#### Attribution

[1](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/case) "Case Meaning in the Cambridge English Dictionary." Cambridge Dictionary. Accessed March 24, 2018. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/case.

[2](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/instance) "Case Meaning in the Cambridge English Dictionary." Cambridge Dictionary. Accessed March 24, 2018. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/case.

Answer (score 1):

In research experiments, you usually hear:

experimental group and control group.

In medicine this is usually treatment group and placebo group (the control).

[Treatment and control groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treatment_and_control_groups)

> The sample or group receiving the drug would be the experimental group
>   (treatment group); and the one receiving the placebo or regular
>   treatment would be the control one.
>  [Experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experiment)

> In contemporary behavioral and social research, scientific
>   experimentation means comparing experimental groups to control groups
>   and establishing the statistical significance of the resulting
>   averages.
>  [Encyclopedia of Statistics in Behavioral Science](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/0470013192.bsa285)